# How can I get the data (DoubleVar) from multiple Tkinter Entry boxes and save them to a .dat file and retrieve them later to repopulate said boxes

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pickle, tkinter-entry, filedialog

First let me say brand new here and brand new to codeing

The whole idea I'm trying to get done is have a list of Parameters that can be saved by the user and used later with out having to change the code

I have a bigger program I am working on, but I have simplified this code to figure this out.  I have the following code that will get and receive a single Entry box,  if I try to add a second entry box to the "save" then it just adds to to the first Entry box like concatenation.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
import pickle
#---------------------------------------------------------------



#---------------------------------------------------------------
root = Tk()
root.title("Cabinet Cut List Calculator")

frame = LabelFrame(root)
frame.pack()
#---------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------
toek = DoubleVar(value=3.5)
default_hgt = IntVar(value=42)
 
parms_list = [toek, default_hgt]



#---------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------
def SaveParms():
    parms_name = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir="/Users/Owner/Desktop/Python/cab databases/Parameters", title="Save Parameters", filetypes=(("Dat Files", "*.dat"),("All Files", "*.*")))

    if parms_name:
        if parms_name.endswith(".dat"):
            pass
        else:
            parms_name = f"{parms_name}.dat"

    parms_list = y.get()

    output_parms = open(parms_name, 'wb')

    pickle.dump(parms_list, output_parms)
        
def LoadParms():
    parms_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/Users/Owner/Desktop/Python/cab databases/Parameters", title="Load Parameters", filetypes=(("Dat Files", "*.dat"),("All Files", "*.*")))

    if parms_name:
            y.delete(0, END)

            input_parm = open(parms_name, "rb")

            load_item = pickle.load(input_parm)

            for i in load_item:
                y.insert(END, i)


def DelParms():
    y.delete(0,END)
    

#---------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------
the_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu = the_menu)
#^^^^^^^^^^
file_menu =  Menu(the_menu, tearoff=False)
the_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu= file_menu)
#^^^^^^^^^^
file_menu.add_command(label="Save Parameters", command= SaveParms)
file_menu.add_command(label="Load Parameters", command= LoadParms)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label="Clear Parameters", command= DelParms)
#---------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------
y = Entry(frame, textvariable=toek)
y.pack(side=RIGHT)
yl= Label(frame, text = "1....")
yl.pack()

frame2 = LabelFrame(root)
frame2.pack()

x = Entry(frame2, textvariable= default_hgt)
x.pack(side=RIGHT)
xl= Label(frame2, text = "2....")
xl.pack()
#---------------------------------------------------------------




root.mainloop()
```

I know this is going to involve some sort of for loop but I cant figure it out. if I try

```
for i in parms_list:
    parms_list =+ i.get()
```

in the Save function I get

```
parms_list =+ i.get()
              ^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

PICKLE is beyond my limited scope of knowledge.

I know there is a simple solution here,  I have tried other things but I am at a loss.

Thanks have a great day

EDIT:
I have been working on this for a couple of days  and this is what I have come up with for the "save" function

```
if parms_name:
    if parms_name.endswith(".dat"):
        pass
    else:
        parms_name = f"{parms_name}.dat"

new_list = []
for i in entry_list:
    entry_name = [key for key, value in globals().items()  if  value == i]
    new_list += [(entry_name[0] + ".get()")]

# print(new_list)
# new_list = [y.get(), x.get()]

output_parms = open(parms_name, 'wb')

pickle.dump(new_list, output_parms)
```

so I am getting closer but the "new_list" is just strings and i need it to run the .get() function on the variable,  I'll keep working at it but if there is any help out there I would appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as most things in life there is more than one way to do things.  I was using .dat files because that was what I was working with a tutorial. After banging my head against a wall and doing research in between I ended up using .ini (config file) and here is my working code.

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
from configparser import ConfigParser
import os
#---------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------
root = Tk()
root.title("Cabinet Cut List Calculator")

frame = LabelFrame(root)
frame.pack()
#---------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------
toek = DoubleVar(value=3.5)
default_hgt = IntVar(value=42)
#---------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------
def SaveParms():
    save_name = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir="/Users/Owner/Desktop/Python/cab databases/Parameters", title="Save Parameters", filetypes=(("ini Files", "*.ini"),("All Files", "*.*")))

    if save_name:
        if save_name.endswith(".ini"):
            pass
        else:
            save_name = f"{save_name}.ini"

    parser = ConfigParser()
    def write_file():
        if save_name:
            parser.write(open(save_name, 'w'))

    if not os.path.exists(save_name):
        parser['parameters'] = {'var1': y.get(), 'var2': x.get()}

        write_file()
        
def LoadParms():
    load_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/Users/Owner/Desktop/Python//cab databases/Parameters", title="Load Parameters", filetypes=(("ini Files", "*.ini"),("All Files", "*.*")))

    if load_name:
        parser = ConfigParser()
        parser.read(load_name)
        saved_toek = parser.get('parameters', 'var1')
        saved_default_hgt = parser.get('parameters', 'var2')
        saved_toek = DoubleVar(value = saved_toek)
        saved_default_hgt = IntVar(value = saved_default_hgt)

        y.configure(textvariable=saved_toek)
        x.configure(textvariable=saved_default_hgt)

def DelParms():
    y.delete(0,END)
    x.delete(0,END)

#---------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------
the_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu = the_menu)
#^^^^^^^^^^
file_menu =  Menu(the_menu, tearoff=False)
the_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu= file_menu)
#^^^^^^^^^^
file_menu.add_command(label="Save Parameters", command= SaveParms)
file_menu.add_command(label="Load Parameters", command= LoadParms)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label="Clear Parameters", command= DelParms)
#---------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------
y = Entry(frame, textvariable=toek)
y.pack(side=RIGHT)
yl= Label(frame, text = "1....")
yl.pack()

frame2 = LabelFrame(root)
frame2.pack()

x = Entry(frame2, textvariable= default_hgt)
x.pack(side=RIGHT)
xl= Label(frame2, text = "2....")
xl.pack()
#---------------------------------------------------------------

root.mainloop()
```